# what is the difference between x=10 & x{10}?

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and i saw 2 types of variable initialization.
what is the difference between int x=10 && int x{10}?
Is int a class and x is an object in this case?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x=10;
    int y{10};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this situation there is no difference. `int z(10);` would be another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: Nicolai Josuttis has a presentation called [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) where he goes through, in excruciating detail, all the different ways things can be initialized in C++.  It can be a bit confusing, and fortunately Nicolai is pretty familiar with C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A difference is that the compiler will have checked that the value `10` was in-range for the type of `y`, rather than a *narrowing conversion*.

For example, if you set them both to 4 billion on a system where `int` happened to be 32 bits...

```
int x=4'000'000'000;
int y{4'000'000'000};
```

...then the second line would be required to produce a compiler error.

In your case though, 10 is in range and there's no difference in behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In this example there is *no* functional difference. The result is the same in both cases.

Technically, the first is "copy initialization" and the second is "direct initialization" and there exist cases where that difference matters, but not here.